# Would this be an example of a Sidon set?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I am a high schooler doing a project on Sidon sets. There aren't much non-convoluted examples of Sidon sets out there on the internet as far as I know so I just want to make sure I understand what they are.

For example, would {1, 2, 3} be a Sidon set since each pairwise sum is different or would it not be since 1 and 2 add to 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\{1,2,3\}$ is not a Sidon set because $1 + 3 = 2 + 2$. The pairwise sums must all be different, even those of the form $a+a$. See the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidon_sequence.

The most trivial examples of Sidon sets are powers of $2$, e.g., $\{1,2,4,8,16\}$. Uniqueness of binary expansion implies the Sidon property. If you want it to be even more intuitive you could look at powers of $10$, e.g. $\{1,10,100,1000,10000\}$. If you pick $x$ and $y$ and tell me $x+y$, I can easily work out what $x$ and $y$ were.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you! I did not know that criteria